# De/encoding hex-numbers with python

Tags: python, registry, mac-address

I'm currently trying to get MAC-Addresses that are saved on my device using python3.8 and I'm getting the following error:

> non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 3

I know it's a decoding error.
Here is the Code:

```
def val2addr(val):   
    if val:
        address = ""
        for ch in val:
            if(not int(ch)):
                address += ':'.join(format(s, '02x') for s in bytes.fromhex(str(ch))).replace("\0", "")
                address = address.strip(' ').replace(' ', ':')[0: 17]
            else:
                address += str(ch)
        return address + ':'.join(format(s, '02x') for s in bytes.fromhex(str(ch))).replace("\0", "")
    return "[!] No MAC [!]"
def print_networks():
    net = u"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion"+\
          "\\NetworkList\\Signatures\\Unmanaged"
    print(str(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) + net)
    key = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, net, 0, (KEY_WOW64_64KEY + KEY_READ))
    print('\n[*] Networks You have Joined:\n')

    for network in range(100):
        try:
            guid = EnumKey(key, network)
            netkey = OpenKey(key, str(guid))
            mac = QueryValueEx(netkey, 'DefaultGatewayMac')[0]
            mac = val2addr(mac)
            network_name = QueryValueEx(netkey, 'Description')[0]
            print("[+] Network Name: " + network_name + "[+] Mac: " + mac)
            CloseKey(netkey)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            break

def main():
    print_networks()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I almost tried every solution I could find here or on the internet and none of them worked for me!

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you give an example of input with the expected output?

Comment: There is no need for input. I have a second method which is "fetching" the information from the registry using winreg. The above error is the only output

Comment: By "input" I mean the parameter you're passing as "val" to this function.  If you're not sure what that input looks like, that may be why you're having difficulty getting things to work!  :) A quick way of debugging that would be to add a `print(val)` to the start of this function so it'll get dumped to the console before it raises an error.

Comment: I took a whirl at running this and got an `Access is denied`.  A single example of the `val` the relevant `val2addr` function receives in your environment would be much more helpful in constructing a minimal reproducible example than seeing the `print_networks` code is.

Comment: Yes you should run your text editor/Idle as admin

Answer (score 0):

The `fromhex` function expects a string that's at least two digits long (since each individual byte is two hex digits), and you're only passing it a single character.  If your intent is to zero-pad the input digit, you can do that by prepending "0" to it like this:

```
def val2addr(val: str) -> str:
    if val:
        address = ""
        for ch in val:
            if not int(ch):
                address += ':'.join(
                    format(s, '02x') for s in bytes.fromhex("0"+ch)
                ).replace("\0", "")
                address = address.strip(' ').replace(' ', ':')[0:17]
            else:
                address += str(ch)
        return address + ':'.join(
            format(s, '02x') for s in bytes.fromhex("0"+ch)
        ).replace("\0", "")
    return "[!] No MAC [!]"


print(val2addr("1234"))  # prints "123404"
```

Comment: Now I have some output (a couple of a mac addresses) but I'm still getting the error

Comment: It works fine for me given the input I tried!  /shrug

Comment: Maybe you could suggest something I could pass to it rather than `"1234"`?

Comment: I think I've to keep locking for other solution. But thank you for your quick response and your help!